# Elasticsearch mongodb and river indexing fail

Tags: mongodb, indexing, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

Dear my (I hope) saviors,

I have a very annoying problem with elasticsearch and mondogdb datas indexing.

The situation is like:
I have 2 mongodb collections, *records* and *pois*, that I need to index on elasticsearch, using river plugin (deprecated, I know).

(Record has a reference (DBRef) to poi and other collections, called otherref# here.)

Now, when I execute the curl call, it happens that....Sometimes **all** records document are indexed, sometimes just **200** (of 140k). Sometimes **900** pois documents are indexed, sometimes just **200** (**never all**, about 70k).

So, it seems that the script doesn't work properly.

I've monitored the /var/log/elasticsearch log , but no error has been logged.

Here the indexing script:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/lw_index_poi" -d ' 
{
 "mappings": {
 "lw_mapping_poi" : {
   "properties" : {
   "position" : {
      "type" : "geo_shape"
    },
   "poi_id" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "index" : "not_analyzed" 
    }
  }
 }
}
}'

curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/lw_index_record" -d ' 
{
  "mappings": {
    "lw_mapping_record" : {
    "date_detection": false,
      "properties" : {
        "other_ref1" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "other_ref2" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "poi_ref" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/lw_index_poi/_meta" -d '
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": { 
    "servers":
    [
      { "host": "mongodb", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "options": { 
      "secondary_read_preference" : false
    },
    "db": "lifewatch",
    "collection": "poi",
    "script": "if (ctx.document.decimalLatitude && ctx.document.decimalLongitude) { ctx.document.position = {}; ctx.document.position.type=\"Point\"; ctx.document.position.coordinates = [ctx.document.decimalLongitude, ctx.document.decimalLatitude]; } ctx.document.poi_id = ctx.document._id; delete ctx.document.decimalLatitude; delete ctx.document.decimalLongitude;"
  }, 
  "index": { 
    "name": "lw_index_poi",
    "type": "lw_mapping_poi"
  }
}'

curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/lw_index_record/_meta" -d '
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": { 
    "servers":
    [
      { "host": "mongodb", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "options": { 
      "secondary_read_preference" : false
    },
    "db": "lifewatch",
    "collection": "record",
    "script": "if (ctx.document.ref1) { ctx.document.ref1 = ctx.document.ref1.id; delete ctx.document.ref1;};if (ctx.document.poi) { ctx.document.poi_ref = ctx.document.poi.id; delete ctx.document.poi;};if (ctx.document.ref2) { ctx.document.ref2 = ctx.document.ref2.id; delete ctx.document.ref2;};"
  }, 
  "index": { 
    "name": "lw_index_record",
    "type": "lw_mapping_record"
  }
}'
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance